# ActiveRecord has_many :through where status = 'pending'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I want to enhance user following with a pending status:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
end
```

So, I added one migration for the status field

```
rails g migration AddStatusToRelationships

class AddStatusToRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :relationships, :status, :string
  end
end
```

Relationships table now looks like

```
id | follower_id | followed_id | status
```

The goal is to display the Relationships with status: "pending"

my approach to enhance

```
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

with something like

```
has_many :followers, -> { where status: "pending" }, through:
               :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

gives me

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.status: SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" 
ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" 
WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ? 
AND "users"."status" = 'pending'
```

So I tried

```
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships -> { 
               where status: "pending" }, source: :follower
```

which returns

```
SyntaxError in UsersController#show app/models/user.rb:20: 
syntax error, unexpected ->, expecting keyword_end ...ough:
:passive_relationships -> { where status: "pending" },
... ... ^ app/models/user.rb:20: 
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ...-> { 
where status: "pending" }, source: :follower ... ^
```

I tried also

```
has_many :pending, through: :passive_relationships, 
    source: :follower, 
    :conditions => ['passive_relationships.status = ?','pending']
```

which returns

```
Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, 
:foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, 
:before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, 
:through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, 
:foreign_type
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :followers, -> { joins (:relationships).where(relationships: { status: 'pending' }) }, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

I would write it in the following form, but not sure, if it is a valid syntax (due to stabby lambda condition):

```
has_many :followers,
  -> { joins(:relationships).where(relationships: { status: 'pending' }) },
  through: :passive_relationships,
  source: :follower
```

Comment: This points to user.status, instead of relationship.status <br/> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.status: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ? AND "users"."status" = 'pending'